# Is there a list of the Caretakers of the Imaginarium Geographica?

Tags: imaginarium-geographica

James Owens wrote a series of books called The Chronicles of the Imaginarium Geographica. This book is an atlas of worlds that have been created when authors write about them (Such as Neverland).

The first book discusses the IG coming to three professors at Oxford, Jack John and Charles, who are rescued early in the book by Bert. It's revealed that

> John, Jack and Charles are JRR Tolkein, CS Lewis and Charles Williams, and Bert is HG Wells.

Subsequent books reveal some of the former Caretakers such as Sir James Barrie, and other known authors.

Is there a list of all of the known Caretakers of the Imaginarium Geographica?